# Problem with point location with locator() function in R

Tags: r

When I click on a plot, the coordinates selected are off.

If I use the locator() function as an example, and click the points on the plot(1:10), this is what I get:

Locator_issue

[image: 1]

I've tried using different versions of both R and RStudio since I don't have this issue on the computers at my university and they run an old version of RStudio. It seemed to work temporarily but not for what I'm working on, and once I turned my computer off and on again I couldn't reproduce it working. My computer is Windows.

Any advice would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the same thing

```r
plot(1:10)
locator(1)
```

but it works fine for me.

I see [this](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/8571) GitHub issue and [this](https://community.rstudio.com/t/locator-returns-incorrect-positions/143558) post in the rstudio forums indicating others have also had problems.

My best guess is this might be a bug in a particular version of RStudio (or even in R itself). The best work around might be to **install the latest versions of both R and RStudio**, then hopefully the problem (possible bug) is no longer there.

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same issue with the locator() function in Rstudio. In my case I found that wrong coordinates are read if zoom settings in global options are different from 100%. Try this:

Tools -> Global Options... -> Appearance -> Zoom: 100%

Answer (score 0):

@Erich made a good point here about the zoom level in Rstudio. It should be 100% otherwise it might not work.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73782801/13880061

But check the zoom level of your windows (in Display settings). It should also be 100%. Usually the default zoom in laptops are 150%. Change that to 100% and then try.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGWJy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Other than setting the zoom level to 100% in RStudio, make sure to set the origin of the graph to (0,0). Use

```
plot(.... , xaxs = "i", yaxs = "i")
```